# Python3- Fill up a 2 dimensions array with the distance to one element

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, maze

I am working on a maze resolution. I have to find the shortest path of a maze and return a string like "LLURD"(with the direction used). To solve this problem I have decomposed it on several steps. One of it is to take the original grid and return a grid where all cells are labelled with a number which is the distance from this cell to the start point.

I think an example is more undestandable:

Input:

> [0,0,0,#,0]
>    [0,X,0,0,0]
>    [0,#,0,0,0]
>    [0,0,0,#,0]
>   
> "X" is the start point
>   
> "#" is a wall
>   
> We can move Up, Down, Right, Left

Output:

> [2,1,2,#,4]
>   [1,X,1,2,3]
>   [2,#,2,3,4]
>   [3,4,3,#,5]

Could someone help me on it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we imagine a 2d grid in the xy plane, the distance between two nodes is the distance in the x plane plus the distance in the y plane.

```
g=[[0,0,0,'#',0],
[0,'X',0,0,0],
[0,'#',0,0,0],
[0,0,0,'#',0]]

def get_dist(start,end): #pass tuples of x,y
    x1,y1=start
    x2,y2=end
    return abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)

def find_start(g): #if you already have it, ignore
    for y,col in enumerate(g):
        for x,item in enumerate(col):
            if item=='X':
                return x,y

start = find_start(g)
for y,col in enumerate(g):
    for x,item in enumerate(col):
        if item == 0: #if is not a start or wall
            g[y][x]=get_dist(start,(x,y))
```

which returns

```
[2, 1, 2, '#', 4]
[1, 'X', 1, 2, 3]
[2, '#', 2, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 3, '#', 5]
```

Comment: I clicked on solved too quickly. In fact, on your return array, the element[3][1]=2 should be equals 3. You have to take in consideration the fact that you can not walk throught wall. But it is maybe not so easy to code..

Comment: You could try using NetworkX which offers lots of nice graph theoretic tools which you can use. If you want to solve it using code, I would suggest trying to write a stepper. You try to step down first in the y plane towards the target, if there is a wall you step around it. Then you step in the x plane, stepping around